# Java Application not functioning completely in Windows 8 (JProgressBar)

Tags: java, windows, swing, swingworker, jprogressbar

I've been working on an issue in which it took me days to find out the cause. 
The issue is that i can't upload data from my java application to my remote database server. 
And finally I figured out what causes the problem. It is actually something in the `JProgressBar`.

This application works fine on Windows 7 desktop but not on Windows 8 tablet.

My code is somewhat like this:

[EDITED]

```
    private class MyTask extends SwingWorker<Void, Void>{

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() {

                ...
                ...
                switch(uploadData()) {
                  ...
                  ...
                  ...
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {

                ....
                ....

            }
    }


    private int uploadData(){
      ....
      ....
      //everything stops here. because it got stuck 
      // with this line
      jProgress.setMaximum(maxItems);

      ....
      //upload
      //return something

    }
```

So I commented that line. Then it proceeded but again stucks up in my next `jProgress` method. So I commented all `jProgress` and it worked.

What could be the issue of `JProgressBar` on Windows 8? Is there any workaround?

Any idea is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming you're updating the `JProgressBar` in the same thread as you upload process, which I assume is separate thread from the UI?

Comment: yes, your assumption is correct

Comment: This may be an issue with the Java and trying to perform updates outside the EDT.  We had some strange behaviour when testing Java 7 (but I was expecting to because the previous developer had no idea about Swing).  Make sure that you are updating any UI components within the context of the EDT.  Try using something like `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` and update the components from within the context of the `Runnable#run` method you pass it...